# Erro na tradução de "source"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Quando acessamos a pagina de revisão do post (que contem o histórico de edições) está escrito "origem"...

[image: tradução de source]

Em inglês está *source*, acho que uma tradução melhor nesse contexto seria "código" ou "código fonte"...

Comment: Provavelmente fonte seria melhor já que não há necessariamente código envolvido e a intenção era essa. Não sei como é traduzido em Portugal. Nós temos traduções que podem parecer estranhas para eles também.

Comment: Para os portuguêses de Portugal diria que ambas `fonte` ou `código` funcionam bem.

Comment: Feito, considerando "fonte" como a alternativa mais votada

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se todos veem isto desta forma, mas o contexto no qual a palavra se encontra é de alguma forma relevante.

#### Utilizando "Origem":

[image: Origem]

Para este caso em particular, ao ver a palavra "origem", vou assumir que ao clicar vou ver o texto original, logo, o texto que estou a visualizar atualmente é uma alteração do original (alteração no sentido de modificação de conteúdo).

#### Utilizando "Fonte":

[image: Fonte]

Ao ver a palavra "fonte", vou assumir que estou a ver um texto formatado, e que se clicar vou ver o mesmo sem formatação.
Aqui a sensação é muito semelhante à diferença entre a página web e o "ver código fonte", ou seja, é ver a mesma informação, mas a página web é mais bonita.

#### A descrição do link

[image: exibir rascunho desta revisão]

Convém também ter em conta a descrição que aparece quando o rato para por cima do link, onde neste caso se lê "exibir rascunho desta revisão":

## Resposta:

A minha opinião é que a palavra "fonte" é a mais adequada para este contexto, pois transmite efetivamente que vamos aceder à fonte do que estamos a visualizar.